# putting bootstrap in header.php , footer.php etc

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am willing to learn about the conversion like .psd then convert to Wordpress with bootstrap framework, because in this modern generation everyone is using tablet and mobile devices, such as iPad. I've heard that bootstrap is very powerful in matching almost every size in all devices, and although I know how to convert the .psd to Wordpress, I don't know how to put Bootstrap in the source directory wp-content like header.php, footer.php etc.. This is hard and confuse. If someone could gave me a tutorial like a video tutorial or links and tips, I would say thank you for the kind and patient response.

Comment: Here is your [answer](https://www.google.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add bootstrap to a wordpress theme,then download the bootstrap .css file, move it into your theme directory, and put the following code in your `functions.php` file:

```
function bootstrap_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'bootstrap_enqueue' );
```

This will include the bootstrap main css file. If boot strap has any associated javascript, then simply add a line after `wp_enqueue_style();` that looks like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
```

And it will all be added to your `wp_head();` function output in your `header.php` file.

But I would caution you: Don't use WordPress and Bootstrap together. Bootstrap is powerful, but it clunky with WordPress. You would be better off using a boilerplate theme like Underscores to start off with, and then reading a quick tutorial on media queries and JS breakpoints.

## Sources

- [WordPress Codex - Enqueue Scripts & Stlyes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
- [Download Bootstrap & Related Styles](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)
- [5 Reasons NOT to use BootStrap](http://www.zingdesign.com/5-reasons-not-to-use-twitter-bootstrap/)
- [Underscores html5 Boilerplate Theme](http://underscores.me/)

Comment: hello remy il ask you something but not related in this topic something about video desktop recorder ..which are the best screen capture recorder that you can make x5 or x4 speed editing..and also free..thank you very much im noob

Comment: Do me a favor and accept this as the answer if it helped you. Also for free screen capture I use [TinyTake by Mango Apps](http://tinytake.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try a simpler approach. There's already a plugin in Wordpress that does what you want, you can check it here: 
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/

If this isn't really what you want you cant check this link:
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial

Comment: **Never** use a plugin for things wordpress already does! You're just adding vulnerability to your site.